# Having trouble getting my Delete and DFS function to work properly

Tags: c, depth-first-search

I am trying to create a Tree data structure which stores information about the Olympic Venues. I have just run into a roadblock and I have realized that my delete function always returns "Element Not Found" and my DFS will find the correct node, but then continue to print out the right side of the tree.

```
Tree * preorder_find(char * find_city, Tree* T)
{
    if(T)
    {

        //if(strcmp(T->Element->city, find_city) == 0)
        //return T;

        printf("%s, %s ... %d\n", T->Element->city, T->Element->country, 
                                                T->Element->year);

        if(strcmp(T->Element->city, find_city) != 0)
        {   
            preorder_find(find_city, T->Left);

            preorder_find(find_city, T->Right);
        }

    }


return T;

}



Tree* delete(char * venue, Tree* T)
{
    Tree* tmp_node;

    if(T==NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "Element not Found\n");
    else
    if(strcmp(venue, T->Element->city) < 0)
        T->Left = delete(venue, T->Left);
    else
    if(strcmp(venue, T->Element->city) > 0)
        T->Right = delete(venue, T->Left);
    else
    if(T->Left && T->Right)
    {
        tmp_node = find_min(T->Right);
        T->Element = tmp_node->Element;
        T->Right = delete(T->Element->city, T->Right);
    }
    else
    {
        tmp_node = T;
        if(T->Left == NULL)
            T = T->Right;
        else if(T->Right == NULL)
            T = T->Left;
        free(tmp_node);
     }

     return T;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please try this `preorder_find()`

   Tree * preorder_find(char * find_city, Tree* T)
   {
       Tree *temp;

   ```
   if(T)
   {

       if(strcmp(T->Element->city, find_city) == 0)
           return T;

       printf("%s, %s ... %d\n", T->Element->city, T->Element->country, 
               T->Element->year);

       if(strcmp(T->Element->city, find_city) != 0)
       {   
           if ((temp = preorder_find(find_city, T->Left))
                   || (temp = preorder_find(find_city, T->Right)))
               return temp;
       }

   }


   return T;
   ```

   }
2. > my delete function always returns "Element Not Found"

   According to your `delete()`, this means the argument `T` of `delete()` always is `NULL`.